# Getting specific portion of string from a Matcher

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'd like to get a portion of a matched string coming from a `Matcher`, like this:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("a.*l.*z");
Matcher match = pat.matcher("abcdlmnoz"); // I'd want to get bcd AND mno
ArrayList<String> values = match.magic(); //here is where your magic happens =)
```

`ArrayList<String>` is only for this example, I could be happy to recieve either a List or individual String items. The best would be what`.htaccess` files and `RewriteRule`'s do:

`RewriteRule (.*)/path?(.*) $1/$2/modified-path/`

Well, putting those (.*) into $arguments would be as cool as an `ArrayList` or accessing `String` separately. I've been looking for something at [Java Matcher API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), but I didn't happen to see anything useful inside.

Thanks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture groups in a regexp match using `(_)`:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("a(.*)l(.*)z");
boolean b = match.matches(); // don't forget to attempt the match
```

Then use [match.group(n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) to get that portion of the capture. The groups are stored in the `match` object.

- [Capturing Groups<sup>Oracle</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the matcher's "group" method and peruse the doc you linked to for references to groups, which is what the parentheses in the regex do :)

Comment: well, I'm such a stupid, I had been around that group() for a while. @paislee put some more info, so the ok goes to him, but you deserved a +1 too, thanks for answering! =)

Comment: Agreed, his answer is more knowledgeable and complete, mine was just a drive-by answer :) glad you found what you needed!

Answer (score 1):

```
...

String testStr = "abcdlmnoz";
String myRE    = "a(.*)l(.*)z";

Pattern myRECompiled = Pattern.compile (myRE, 
                                        DOTALL);
Matcher myMatcher    = myRECompiled.matcher (testStr);

myMatcher.find ();

System.out.println (myMatcher.group (1));
System.out.println (myMatcher.group (2));

...
```